# Perl Fibonacci number program with array references?

Tags: perl

EDIT: SOLVED. See solution below.

I wrote the following Fibonacci number program for the first 10 numbers; however I can't get it to work. It keeps telling me that `Use of uninitialized value $secondLast in addition (+) at fib.plx line 22.` and it runs forever. I'm a beginner Perl programmer so I'm sure the error is very simple. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub fib(\@$);

my @defaultNums = (1,1);
my $max = 10;
fib(@defaultNums,10);

sub fib(\@$)
{
        my $nums_ref = $_[0];
        my $max = $_[1];
        foreach(@{$nums_ref})
        {
                print "$_, ";
        }
        print "\n";
        my $last = pop (@{$nums_ref});
        my $secondLast = pop (@{$nums_ref});
        my $sum = $last + $secondLast;
        push (@{$nums_ref}, $sum);
        if( scalar  @{$nums_ref} >= $max) { return; }
        fib (@{$nums_ref},$max);
        print "\n";
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED. See solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few notes on your program:

- It is important that you avoid using subroutine prototypes unless you are *absolutely* sure about what you are doing. Prototypes are primarily intended for writing replacements for Perl built-in operators, and that is something that is rarely required. You should explicity pass a reference to an array by writing the call as `fib(\@defaultNums, 10)`.
- The first two values in the Fibonacci sequence are zero and one. You have seeded your sequence with the second and third values which, while it will work fine, isn't mathematically correct.
- Because Perl is sensitive to context, you can remove the `scalar` call to compare the number of elements in the array. You can also used the `if` statement modifier to avoid a lot of noise, so your `return` line becomes `return if @{$nums_ref} >= $max`.
- Your chosen solution - to replace the items popped from the array - is inefficient and counter-intuitive. Using list assignment and Perl's ability to index array elements from the end of the array lets you write `my ($last, $secondLast) = @{$nums_ref}[-1, -2]` which doesn't remove the elements and so they don't need to be replaced.

Here is quick rewrite of your program to show you what you've been missing!

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @defaultNums = (0, 1);

fib(\@defaultNums, 10);

sub fib {

  my ($nums_ref, $max) = @_;
  print join(', ', @$nums_ref), "\n";

  my ($last, $secondLast) = @{$nums_ref}[-1, -2];
  my $sum = $last + $secondLast;
  push @$nums_ref, $sum;
  return if @{$nums_ref} >= $max;

  fib($nums_ref, $max);
}
```

**output**

```
0, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 1, 1, 2
0, 1, 1, 2, 3
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my mistake. I'm popping off of the array twice each time, so I need to remember to push those numbers back on before I push on $sum. Thanks anyways.